# Excel VBA how to use ROUNDUP(ROW(##)) in a formula?

Tags: excel, vba

If the activecell is not in the first column, it is supposed to create a new column in column A and insert the rounded-up values of the row numbers divided by 10.000.
Don't really find how to insert this variable into the formula

```
If ActiveCell.Column < 1 Then _
   Range("A:A").Insert
   Range("A10").EntireColumn.Insert
   Range("A:A").Formula = "=ROUNDUP(ROW(A" & rowNum & ")/10000;0)"
```

Comment: Change the `;` to `,`, or change the `.Formula` to `.FormulaLocal`.

Comment: Also, `Range("A:A").Formula` writes the formula to every single cell in column A. You could perhaps [find the last row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11169445/error-in-finding-last-used-cell-in-excel-with-vba) first, if that's not the intended behavior.

Comment: Still not working when i change to FormulaLocal. Excel receives this in the formula bar : =ROUNDUP(@ROW(A)/10000;0)

Comment: Then use `.Formula2Local` since your version of Excel supports Dynamic Array formulas.

Comment: Also, how are you determining `rowNum`? Where do you have `rowNum = ...`?

Comment: Still not working BigBen, since the output is excel is #NAME and the corresponding formula is indeed =ROUNDUP(@ROW(A)/10000;0), I suppose there must me smth wrong in the way that I want to input the row numbers, as it can't read it. No?

Comment: I haven't defined rowNum... I thought it would for each cell refer to the rowNumber it is in...

Comment: Then use `"=ROUNDUP(ROW()/10000;0)"`

Comment: I wanted it to be a variable input for all cells differently

Comment: `ROW()` without parameters will refer to the row the formula is in.

Comment: BigBen thanks a lot man! Great help!